# How to use AJAX request to select radio button value and text inputs upon callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

The form data fills properly on all input text fields. But for the radio buttons nothing happens except the value for the element gets changed, but no visual. I know its because based on the Class name, it changes the value. But how do i differentiate between field inputs vs radio inputs? thanks!

```js
$(function() {
   $(".task-listing").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:8090/HELPERSITE/src/php/listing-info-get.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: 'pid=' + $(this).attr("id"),
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);

        Object.keys(response[0]).map(function(k) {
            var el = $('.' + k);
            if (el.prop('type') == 'radio') {
              el.filter(function(i, button) {
                return button.value == response[0][k];
              }).prop('checked', true);
            } else {
              $('.' + k).val(response[0][k]);
            }
        })
      }
  });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `checked` property of the appropriate button if the type is `radio`.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".task-listing").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'http://localhost:8090/HELPERSITE/src/php/listing-info-get.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: 'pid=' + $(this).attr("id"),
          success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);

            Object.keys(response[0]).map(function(k) {
                var el = $('.' + k);
                if (el.prop('type') == 'radio') {
                  el.filter(function(i, button) {
                    return button.value == response[0][k];
                  }).prop('checked', true);
                } else {
                  $('.' + k).val(response[0][k]);
                }
                if (response.negotiate == 'approve') {});
            }
          })
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="task-title-reg" name="task-title-reg" value="">
<textarea class="task-description-reg" name="task-description-reg" rows="4" cols="50" value=""></textarea>

<label for="local-reg">Local</label>
<input type="radio" name="task-location-reg" value="Local">
<label for="remote-reg">Remote</label>
<input type="radio" class="task-location-reg" name="task-location-reg" value="Remote">

<label for="approve-reg">Approve</label>
<input type="radio" class="task-negotiations-reg" name="negotiate" value="Approve">
<label for="deny-reg">Deny</label>
<input type="radio" class="task-negotiations-reg" name="negotiate" value="Deny">
```